# How do I update attributes of a nested model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a company model, that `accepts_nested_attributes_for :users` and my controller looks like this:

```
def create
  @company = Company.new(company_params)
  if @company.save
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private

def company_params
  params.require(:company).permit(:name, :company_size , users_attributes: [:id, :name])
end
```

what I'd like to do is set the admin boolean I have in user to true.

Essentially what I'm doing is making a user sign up by creating a company, and also registering their user, and thus making the person registering the company an admin.

Comment: can you do something like company[:users][:admin]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply alter the User object before it is saved.

```
def create
  @company = Company.new(company_params)
  @company.user.admin = true
  if @company.save
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

You could also do this as a a model callback. However your implementation might be a little to naive. What happens if a user belongs to several companies?